# GIT: Fix File only Locally

Tags: git

I have the problem with a PHP-Programm, I maintain via git. There is a config file, that has to be in the repo, that new checkouts have that inside, but the file needs to be changed locally.

.gitignore is no solution, because then the file will not be in repo anymore.

I want to fix that file locally just at my machine (or at any machine) that it is ignored when doing a git add . and it istn't shown in git status as changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `git update-index --assume-unchanged` as described here: http://blog.pagebakers.nl/2009/01/29/git-ignoring-changes-in-tracked-files/

Answer (score 1):

The common technique for that kind of tasks is to put that file into repo with suffix `.dist`
Then each local checkout copies "dist file" and make changes to it.
(Original name has to be put in `.gitignore`)

Comment: Doesn't Solve actual problem, but is good idea for following Repos. Thanks!